# Android Studio - Phone Calls

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to make an App which make Multiple Phone calls (One after another) by pushing a Button. I've got an Array where the telephone numbers are included.

Thats my current code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String[]numbers={
        "number1",
        "number2"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length;i++) {

                if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    dialContactPhone(numbers[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void dialContactPhone(final String phoneNumber) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, null)));
}

private void startActivityForResult(Intent tel) {

}
```

}

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: i can call 1 number, but i can not call all numbers from the Array

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5869351/3226984).
And after first call is finished start next.

Answer (score 0):

You are only able to make one call because you are dialling both the numbers at the same time.

You should make the first call, then wait for that call to end and then make the next call.

```
private class EndCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            //wait for phone to go offhook (probably set a boolean flag) so you know your app initiated the call.
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
        }
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            //when this state occurs, and your flag is set, restart your app
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

            // Make your next call from here.
        }
    }
}
```

READ_PHONE_STATE permission required.